# Using variables recursively in python

Tags: python

Can i use variables to set my zip patch inset of entering it manualy

Example part of the code that works fine

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
zip_folder(r'Monday' ,
           r'Monday.zip')
```

But can i use a variable insted of just a entering the day myself, for this second example i get a "invalid syntax" error

```
 today = "Monday"
 today_zip = "Monday.zip"

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 zip_folder(r today,
            r today_zip)

 import zipfile
 import sys
 import os

def zip_folder(folder_path, output_path):
"""Zip the contents of an entire folder (with that folder included
in the archive). Empty subfolders will be included in the archive
as well.
"""
parent_folder = os.path.dirname(folder_path)
# Retrieve the paths of the folder contents.
contents = os.walk(folder_path)
try:
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(output_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, folders, files in contents:
        # Include all subfolders, including empty ones.
        for folder_name in folders:
            absolute_path = os.path.join(root, folder_name)
            relative_path = absolute_path.replace(parent_folder + '\\',
                                                  '')
            print "Adding '%s' to archive." % absolute_path
            zip_file.write(absolute_path, relative_path)
        for file_name in files:
            absolute_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            relative_path = absolute_path.replace(parent_folder + '\\',
                                                  '')
            print "Adding '%s' to archive." % absolute_path
            zip_file.write(absolute_path, relative_path)
    print "'%s' created successfully." % output_path
except IOError, message:
    print message
    sys.exit(1)
except OSError, message:
    print message
    sys.exit(1)
except zipfile.BadZipfile, message:
    print message
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    zip_file.close()


   if __name__ == '__main__':
   zip_folder(r'Monday',
           r'Monday.zip')
```

Comment: The `r` belongs to the string, not to the call - and it's completely unneccessary here, simply remove it. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for a description of what it does; it is used to ignore most escape sequences inside of strings.

Comment: what is the r doing?

Comment: I think it would be better if you call a function inside your 'if' boilerplate and pass parameters, like : myzip_fun(today, today_zip)

Comment: take a look of a full code, might make some sense now

Comment: @user3914163 no, it makes less sense than before. If you get a syntax error, _post the exact error message_; nobody can be bothered to read through that code to find a typo or something. Also, as the code is currently formatted you'd get a syntax error due to incorrect indentation; check your formatting please.

Comment: You should do at least some of the work yourself - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to specify `r` here:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_folder( today, today_zip)
```

would work fine. `r`,`u` etc are qualifiers for strings in python, which is not needed here in your case.

Comment: How did this answer get accepted?  I agree about the raw prefix to the strings, but the op says it didn't work.  What is needed is the full traceback, and the code that it points to